# How do I make a sprite fire a bullet in a direction using SFML and C++?

Tags: c++, 2d, game-design, sfml, xcode

I'm learning game programming for the first time using sfml and c++. I have sucessfully animated my sprite in all four directions watching some video tutorials. But now i want my sprite to fire in a facing direction. I just want to do it a very basic way. It would be great if i could get some idea of it. I am using xcode 7.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to keep track of the player orientation when you update it. It can be as simple as setting a vector value when the player presses the movement keys. Something like

```
if (leftKeyPressed)
{
    playerForward = vec2(-1, 0)
}
if (rightKeyPressed)
{
    playerForward = vec2(1, 0)
}
if (upKeyPressed)
{
    playerForward = vec2(0, -1)
}
if (downKeyPressed)
{
    playerForward = vec2(0, 1)
}
```

Now, you can use the variable `playerForward` to set the movement direction and even initial position of the bullet. You probably want to spawn the bullets somewhere around the player, so you can use the movement direction and multiply it by a constant size to move it relative to the player's origin. Something like the following pseudo code should do.

```
if (shootKeyPressed)
{
    vec2 bulletPosition = playerCenter + playerForward * playerSize / 2;
    vec2 bulletVelocity = playerForward * Bullet::Speed;

    spawnBullet(bulletPosition, bulletVelocity);
}
```

Comment: I want to press Space button to fire and use arrow keys to move the sprite. I have succesfully moved the sprite in all directions but now i want to press space to fire a bullet i any direction that sprite is facing

Comment: And that's what my pseudo code here does for you. Did you even read it? The answer directly addresses the issue of shooting the bullet to the correct direction from the correct position.

Comment: Yeah thanks I did but may be couldn't gather it somehow. I ll have a look at it again and maybe bother you again. Thanks, appreciate it.

Comment: Yeah do ask if you need something specific clarified, but restating your whole problem as you did above doesn't really help. I'll be happy to help with something specific that you're still uncertain about.

Comment: @gitamgadtaula Were you able to solve your issue? If you did and you found my answer helpful, don't forget to accept the answer so that others can find help in the future more easily.